# Conditional replacing in RapidMiner

Tags: rapidminer

As novice in Rapidminer magics please advise how to solve - **conditional replacement**

I have a table and in some rows the values of certain columns match externally prescribed rules that condition that values in other columns in the same row need to be replaced with externally predetermined values. Let us say that characteristics of anymals are in columns and columns have it no wings and ugly looking and weighs a ton and other column says "elefant", but in some rows the values are "has wings" and "looks nice" and "you can cook it" so the answer is obviously "duck"

Orther rows do not have matching values so nothing is changed
**Please tell me the steps**
(no Decision Trees or other stochasticity please)